# Keycloak administration page not loading

Tags: ubuntu, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I am trying to setup a keycloak server on AWS EC2 for testing purpose running on Ubuntu. However when I try to load the console page it shows a blank page in browser.

Keycloak is completely new and not sure what changes are required.

The settings I used to spin up the keycloak server are below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt install -y openjdk-17-jre-headless
cd /srv
sudo wget https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases/download/17.0.1/keycloak-17.0.1.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf keycloak-17.0.1.tar.gz
sudo rm -rf keycloak-17.0.1.tar.gz
sudo sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out server.crt.pem
#####Add lines to conf/keycloak.conf
sudo sed -i '$ a https-certificate-file=/srv/server.crt.pem' /srv/keycloak-17.0.1/conf/keycloak.conf
sudo sed -i '$ a https-certificate-key-file=/srv/server.key.pem' /srv/keycloak-17.0.1/conf/keycloak.conf
sudo sed -i '$ a hostname=<PUBLIC-IP-OF-EC2-INSTANCE>:8443' /srv/keycloak-17.0.1/conf/keycloak.conf
sudo su
bin/kc.sh build
export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
bin/kc.sh start
```

[image]

Comment: Hypothesis 1 : By default, Keycloak doesn't like when you hit it from a non-private IP using SSL. 
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/ : "Set Require SSL to one of the following SSL modes:

external requests:: Users can interact with Keycloak without SSL so long as they stick to private IP addresses such as localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, and 172.16.x.x. If you try to access Keycloak without SSL from a non-private IP address, you will get an error." 
Can you try to configure properly the DNS ? Use a static IP, associate it with a DNS and create your cert around